# In the Radiation dominated era, why is k = 0 a good approximation?

Tags: cosmology

In the radiation dominated era of the universe, a standard approximation to use is that $k = 0$.

Now we know we can calculate a value of $k$ via:

$$k=\frac{\mathrm{H}_{0}^{2}}{c^{2}}\left(\Omega_{0}-1\right)$$

by evaluating at the present day.

Equally, we also know that if $k=0$ exactly, it will stay this way for ever as reflected in:

$$\Omega(a)=\frac{\Omega_{0}}{a\left(1-\Omega_{0}\right)+\Omega_{0}}$$

The most recent measurements of the CMB imply that $k$ is indeed very close to $0$.

Is this why we assume $k=0$ in the early universe, or is there a more fundamental reason than 'it just seems to be that way'? When